# Write a text file encoded in UTF-8 with a BOM through java.nio

Tags: java, character-encoding, nio

I have to write the output of a database query to a csv file.

Unfortunately, many people in my company are not able to use a nice editor like Notepad++ and keep opening csv files with Excel.

When I write a text/csv file using `java.nio` like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path path = Paths.get("U:\\temp\\TestOutput\\csv_file.csv");
    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("Übernahme", "Außendarstellung", "€", "@", "UTF-8?");

    try {
        Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the file gets created successfully and is encoded in UTF-8.

**Now the problem is the missing BOM in that file.**

There is no BOM (Notepad++ bottom-right encoding label shows <kbd>UTF-8</kbd>) which is no problem for Notepad++

[image]

but obviously it is for Excel

[image]

and when I use Notepad++'s option **Encoding > Convert to UTF-8-BOM**, save & close it and open the file in Excel afterwards, it correctly displays all the values, no encoding issues are left.

That leads to the following question:

**Can I force `java.nio.file.Files.write(...)` to add a BOM when using `StandardCharsets.UTF-8` or is there any other way in `java.nio` to achieve the desired encoding?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no direct way in the standard Java NIO library to write text files in UTF-8 with BOM format.

But that's not a problem, since BOM is nothing but a special character at the start of a text stream represented as `\uFEFF`. Just add it manually to the CSV file, f.e.:

```java
List<String> lines = 
    Arrays.asList("\uFEFF" + "Übernahme", "Außendarstellung", "€", "@", "UTF-8?");
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the encoding is working if I add the character as first line, but it has a downside: now the first line is always empty. I think I have to appen the first line to `"\uFEFF"`, will try...

Comment: @deHaar, that's because `Files.write` adds a line separator after the BOM character. Appending the first line to it should help.

Comment: OK, thanks, have tried it and that fixes it without any downside...

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest instead of using "\uFEFF" + "Übernahme", use as "\uFEFF", "Übernahme".
Benefit of doing this is, it will not change the actual data of the file.
In the case of using opencsv API, you are having the headers in first line and data from second line, then adding "," after BOM character, you can have the same header intact, without any prefix to header. If the header got updated then you have to update the code for the data and header mapping too.
If you are using the properties file for header and data mapping then you have to just add an extra mapping for "\uFEFF" as "\uFEFF"=TEMP there.